# Исключить  textarea из form

Tags: dojo, javascript

Привет, есть такой скрипт в лэйауте :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            dojo.fadeIn({node: "#{uiHelper.clientId['formid']}"}).play();

            // switching-off Enter key, in-avoidance navigation bugs
            var form = dojo.byId("#{uiHelper.clientId['formid']}");

            dojo.connect(form, "onkeypress", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
                    dojo.stopEvent(event);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Блокировать enter нужно во всех элементах form, кроме textarea (используется на странице):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        var dijitWidget = dijit.byId("#{uiHelper.clientId['answer']}");
        if (dijitWidget != null) {
            dijitWidget.destroy();
        }
        var jsfElement = dojo.byId("#{uiHelper.clientId['answer']}");
        try {
            var dojoElement = new dijit.form.Textarea({

                required: true,
                style: "-moz-box-sizing: border-box; height: 100px !important; max-width: 850px !important; min-height: 100px !important; min-width: 850px !important; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 500px !important; wrap:off !important; resize: none;",
                name: dojo.attr(jsfElement, "name"),
                value: jsfElement.value,
                onKeyPress: function(){Console.log("haha");}
            }, jsfElement);
            dojoElement.startup();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Вопрос: Как исключить из вот этого условия **Textarea**:

```
if (event.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
   dojo.stopEvent(event);
}
```

Или, может быть, есть какие то другие варианты решения проблемы?
В `javasript` не силен... 
**Заранее спасибо за ответы!**

Answer (score 1):

Если кому то вдруг пригодится вот решение проблемы:

```
dojo.connect(form, "onkeypress", function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
                        var k = document.activeElement;
                        if("textarea" != k.type )
                            dojo.stopEvent(event);
                    }
```

Все легко и просто, оказывается :)